# Paging and sorting using a stored procedure in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure for paging. Now I am looking for column sorting.

My working paging stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE paging (PageSize     IN     INT,
                  PageIndex    IN     INT,
                  SortColumn   IN     VARCHAR,
                  PageData        OUT Page) AS
    FirstIndex   INT;
    LastIndex    INT;
    SortCol      VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    LastIndex := PageSize * (PageIndex + 1);
    FirstIndex := LastIndex - PageSize + 1;
    SortCol := SortColumn;

    OPEN PageData FOR
        SELECT *
          FROM (SELECT a.*, ROWNUM AS rnum
                  FROM (  SELECT *
                            FROM table_name
                        ORDER BY SortCol) a
                 WHERE ROWNUM <= LastIndex)
         WHERE rnum >= FirstIndex;
END paging;
/
```

Comment: Add your ORDER BY clause to the innermost sub-query, ie `(SELECT * form table)` will become `(SELECT * form table ORDER BY transactionDate)`

Comment: Could you fix your example code please: In `Open PageData ....` you have three closing parenthesis. But only two opening.

Comment: @cha  how to make ORDER BY transactionDate DESC parameterize in oracle those are input parmenter we have to pass its value

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you make use of a wonderful feature called Dynamic SQL ([Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011)).

I have also modified your SQL query and used `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `rownum`. It is a more robust method of ordering and numbering the output rows than the latter.

I have also removed a few variables that I don't think were needed from your PL/SQL:

```
PROCEDURE paging (PageSize     IN     INT,
                  PageIndex    IN     INT,
                  SortColumn   IN     VARCHAR2, -- Assuming this always contains
                                                -- the ordering column name
                  PageData        OUT Page) AS
    FirstIndex   INT;
    LastIndex    INT;
    v_sql        VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    LastIndex := PageSize * (PageIndex + 1);
    FirstIndex := LastIndex - PageSize + 1;

    v_sql :=  'SELECT *'
            ||'  FROM (SELECT a.*,'
            ||'              ROW_NUMBER() '
            ||'                OVER (ORDER BY ' || SortColumn || ') AS rnum'
            ||'          FROM table_name a)'
            ||' WHERE rnum BETWEEN FirstIndex AND LastIndex';

    OPEN PageData FOR v_sql;

END paging;
/
```

Comment: Great answer. Is dynamic SQL *required* to `ORDER BY SortColumn` ?

Comment: Yes. How else would you pass the name of the column? Biding the index of the column doesn't work in Oracle (and I doubt, in other databases too). So you need to pass the column name to the query and hence you need Dynamic SQL, with the column name concatenated into the query (and not bound like placeholders).

Comment: That's what I thought. But as the OP didn't use dynamic SQL, I though there was maybe some trick to do otherwise. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

This SP alone doing all the three things in Oracle, `Paging, Sorting and Filtering` of records.

```
create or replace procedure GetResults 
(
 p_userId In Number,
 p_dueDateFrom In Date,
 p_dueDateTo in Date,
 p_durationMax in Number,
 p_durationMin in Number,
 p_sortColumn In Varchar2,
 p_sortOrder In Varchar2,
 p_pageSize In Number,
 p_pageIndex in number,
 cv_1 OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
as 
v_FirstIndex   NUMBER;
v_LastIndex    NUMBER;
begin
-- Paging
  v_LastIndex := p_pageSize * (p_pageIndex + 1);
  v_FirstIndex := v_LastIndex - p_pageSize + 1;

 OPEN cv_1 FOR 

  SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.*, ROWNUM AS rnum
              FROM (Select * From Newjob nj Where nj.userId = p_userId  
               -- Filtering
             And ((p_dueDateFrom IS NULL AND p_dueDateTo Is NULL) OR 
                  (nj.Due_Date >= p_dueDateFrom and nj.Due_Date <= p_dueDateTo)
                 )
             And ((p_durationMax IS NULL AND p_durationMin Is NULL) OR 
                  (nj.Duration >= p_durationMax and nj.Duration <= p_durationMin)
                 )   
             -- Sorting     
            order by   
            Case when p_sortOrder = 'Ascending' And p_sortColumn = 'DUE_DATE' then  nj.Due_Date End,
            Case When p_sortOrder = 'Ascending' And p_sortColumn = 'DURATION' then nj.DURATION end,     
            Case when p_sortOrder = 'Descending' And p_sortColumn = 'DUE_DATE' then  nj.Due_Date End desc,
            Case When p_sortOrder = 'Descending' And p_sortColumn = 'DURATION' then nj.DURATION end desc)a
   WHERE ROWNUM <= v_LastIndex)    
   WHERE rnum >= v_FirstIndex;
end;
```